# How to `pip install` Python module in RStudio?

Tags: python, r, pip, r-markdown

Hoping for some help.  How does one `pip install` a Python package for reticulating from within an RStudio R-Markdown (*.Rmd*) file?

For example, the [`lasio` Python package](https://pypi.org/project/lasio/) is not available through `conda`.  Hence, the following *.Rmd* code was not able to add the package to my environment:

````
```{r}
library(reticulate)
py_install("lasio")    # did not work
```
````

I also tried to install the package with Python code (to no avail):

````
```{python}
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m install lasio    # did not work

$ python -m pip install lasio    # also did not work
```
````

Turns out that the `lasio` package could be installed/added to my environment by typing `pip install lasio` in RStudio's ***Terminal*** window/tab.  However, I'm hoping for code that can be run with *.R* or *.Rmd* code so as to automate the process when ported to another machine. Thanks.

Comment: Try using `system()` to call the `pip install` command within R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`py_install()`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/py_install.html) has a `pip` argument that you can set to `TRUE` which should use `pip` to install your module:

```
py_install("lasio",pip=TRUE)
```

Alternatively, you can use `system2()` to pass calls directly into the terminal.

```
system2("pip install lasio")
```